# How to catch an error (message) after a request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a request, and if the status is not 200, I should throw an error with an error message

```js
apiService.createNewUser(data).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
    } else {
        throw new Error(???)
    }
}).then((newUserData) => {
            ..success

}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('2', err.message)
})
```

in response I have next object

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/create"
__proto__: Response
```

and if users not found I have message in next then, but if user not found I need throw Error with this message and I dont now how make it

Maybe I need to parse response somhow bebore pass to catch block

Comment: throw an error in catch block?

Comment: the question is how to put error message from response in error object

Comment: what I need to put in error object

Comment: u have to use error boundary to catch errors and inform it to the user. and then u can throw error in catch block which will throw error only if any error occurs.

Comment: response have body and have message and I need to put message to error to dispaly it

Comment: but I dont know how get message I dont see it

Comment: can u add response u r getting?

Comment: update question

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
 apiService.createNewUser(data).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        } else {
             return Promise.reject(response)
        }
    }).then((newUserData) => {
                ..success
    
    }.catch((err) => {
                return err.json()
            }).then((err) => {
                console.log(err.message)
            })
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation as to how this solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your code by simply adding an extra try catch.

```
try {
    apiService.createNewUser(data).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        } else {
            throw new Error( ?? ? )
        }
    }).then((newUserData) => {
        ..success

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('2', err.message)
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
}
```